# retrieve distinct values of manytomanyfield of another manytomanyfield

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a simple question but multiple google searches left me without a nice solution. Currently I am doing the following:

```py
allowed_categories = self.allowed_view.all().difference(self.not_allowed_view.all())
users = []
for cat in allowed_categories:
    for member in cat.members.all():
        users.append(member)
return users
```

I have a `ManyToManyField` to `Objects` that also have a `ManyToManyField` for instances of `User`s. In the code above, I am trying to get all the users from all those categories and get a list of all `User`s.
Later I would like the same in a method `allowed_to_view(self, user_instance)` but that's for later.

How would I achieve this using Django ORM without using nested for-loops?

[edit]
My models are as follows:

```py
class RestrictedView(models.Model):
    allowed_view = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    not_allowed_view = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've made the following one-liner with only one query towards the database. It took me some time...

```py
users = User.objects.filter(pk__in=self.allowed_view.all().values("users").difference(self.not_allowed_view.all().values("users")))
```

This gives me a nice queryset with only the users that are in the allowed_view and explicitly not in the not_allowed_view.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing you database structure / models.py file its hard to say, but you can do a search on member objects like so:

```py
members_queryset = Member.objects.filter(
    category = <allowed categories>,
    ...
)

users += list(members.all())
```

Comment: I could. But does this have a better performance than my current solution?

Comment: The best performance is to add `select_related` or `prefetch_related` to your querysets so you aren't repeating queries.

Comment: that results in a next error `Calling QuerySet.select_related() after difference() is not supported.` :\

Comment: Try it before difference?